# Php update (Package 5.5-frontenddev is already installed)?

Tags: php, macos, localhost

I am trying to update my Php to 5.5 on a mac (by pasting "curl -s http://php-osx.liip.ch/install.sh | bash -s 5.5" into terminal). The download starts but gives the following message before the downloads stops:

Package 5.5-frontenddev is already installed at version 5.5.5-20131020-233829. You wanted to install version 5.5.5-20131020-233829.

Is there anyway around this as I really need 5.5 in order to continue with my course!
Thank you in advance for any help.
Margate

Answer (score 8):

You should be able to delete the packager registry log and just try the command again, making sure you have removed the relevant folders from `/usr/local/php5-*`.

The file is located at:

`/usr/local/packager/registry.log`

Comment: Hi, I have searched for these paths and folders but to no avail. I have reinstalled MAMP (out of desperation) and this is running 5.5 no problem but I do not want to use MAMP! I now have 2 versions of php installed in different locations! I am able to find the MAMP directory via applications/MAMP everything is in there but the 5.3 files I cannot seem to locate anywhere!?

Comment: It will be a hidden file on your system. Type `open /usr/local/packager` in Terminal to locate the registry.log and type `open /usr/local` and search for the folders named php5-* (usually php5-5.5.lots-of-numbers-here and delete them.

A personal recommendation not related to the issue. I was running into the same issues you have, I decided to install through homebrew instead - https://github.com/josegonzalez/homebrew-php